# I need to pass both params and a query into ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to dynamically construct a link to another route on an angular app using ui-sref with both params and query params. Example:

```
    <a class="clr-secondary" ui-sref="app.topic.individual.conversation.single
({cid:comment.activityItemId, cid:itemId})">{{comment.subject}}</a>
```

This constructs a link that looks something like

```
www.website.com/pass/11/conversations/178
```

I need to also add a query parameter to the end of this so the entire url will look like

```
www.website.com/pass/11/conversations/178?comment_id=126
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the query parameters to the url in the ui router config:

```
.state('yourstate', {
  url: '/pass/:activityId/conversations/:conversationId?comment_id',
  templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
  controller: 'YourController'
});
```

Then pass the comment_id just like you pass the other params:

```
<a class="clr-secondary" ui-sref="app.topic.individual.conversation.single
({activityId:comment.activityItemId, conversationId:itemId, comment_id: 126})">{{comment.subject}}</a>
```